# Ruby calling an array in a function

Tags: arrays, ruby, function, each

Trying to call an array from a function to just `assert_equal` to make sure it is returning the intended string.

here is my function:

```
def array_mod
  a = *(1..100)
  a.each { |i| if i % 3 == 0  && i % 5 == 0; i = "fifteen" elsif i % 3 == 0; i = "three" elsif i % 5 == 0; i = "five" else i = i end }
end
```

and here is my attempt at calling it.

```
require "minitest/autorun"
require_relative "array_modulus.rb"

class TestArrayFunction < Minitest::Test
  def test_array1
    results = array_mod
    assert_equal(100, results.length)
  end

  def test_array2
    results = array_mod
    assert_equal("three", results[2])
  end
end
```

The test passes the `results.length`, but returns the `"three"` as `3`, an integer.

I know I could create an array and do it like

```
def abc
  arr = []
  *(1..100) do |i|
    if i % 3 == 0
      i = "three"
    else 
      i = I
    end
```

But I was curious if I could do it with the previous way of writing it.

Sorry for any mistakes, I wrote this on my phone.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why did you choose one of the options I marked as non-idiomatic instead of one of the options I marked as idiomatic in my answer to your earlier question?

Comment: I was attempting to go down the same line of thought that I began on. I was curious if it was possible the non-idiomatic way.

Comment: sorry if i was asking a duplicate question. When I mentioned that the comment box is not very good for posting code for further questions, and you said to ask another question, i thought this was what you meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to to use map. Try this:

```
def array_mod
  a = *(1..100)

  a.map do |i|
    if i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0
      "fifteen"
    elsif i % 3 == 0
      "three"
    elsif i % 5 == 0
      "five"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The value of a method is the last expression evaluated in the method. In your case, it is `a.each {...}`. This method **always** returns `a`.

Actually, it is not clear to me what you intended to do with the `each` block, as the only thing it does is changing the local variable `i` inside the block, which doesn't affect anything outside the block.

Hence, your method is equivalent to

```
def array_mod
   (1..100).to_a
end
```

Comment: Apparently the OP wanted to change the array element by assigning a new value to `i`. As if it was pass by reference.

Comment: Stefan is correct. I am attempting to change the value of i.